# ubuntu installing issue 16.04.1 on windows 10 HP laptop

Tags: ubuntu-one

Sir i want to remove win 10 and install ubuntu 16.04.1 but when i m installing it is showing "force UEFI installation?...this machine's firmware has started the installer in UEFI mode but it looks like there may exist operating systems already installed using "BIOS compatibility mode"...If you wish to install in UEFI mode and don't care about keeping the ability to boot one of the existing systems, you have the option to force that here......". 
SIR TELL ANY PROCEDURE TO ITSTALL UBUNTU BUT I CAN INSTALL WINDOWS IN FUTURE AS WELL (SAFE METHOD) ?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the Laptops shipping now have UEFI BIOS and OS (Win10) mostly installed in that mode itself. But here it looks like your OS is installed in legacy mode. So always it is better idea to install both of your OS in same mode. Here your Ubuntu installation have detected UEFI mode and asking whether to install in UEFI mode or switch to legacy mode. So it is better you press a button to cancel forcing or something like that.

For your second question, of course you can install windows without any problem when you want to.

Comment: So i finally i can install it .... Without facing issue in future

Comment: yes of course. please follow some tutorial so that you get into trouble while   installing Ubuntu. I am always happy to help..!